# Access html inside content tag in Polymer

Tags: polymer, web-component

I am trying to access the html that i wrote inside my own polymer-element but it isn't working. How can I achieve this?

**index.html**

`<my-element> content I am trying to access </my-element>`

**my-element.html**

```
<polymer-element name='my-element'>
    <template>
        <content id='content'></content>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            ready: function(){
                console.log('html: '+this.$.content.innerHTML);
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

**console**

`html:`

Comment: You don't have to wrap your content tag into a template. You just can use <content> by itself and your original implementation will work. Templates are good for reusing parts of a document, e.g. a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the implementation inserts content nodes as *siblings* of `content`, not as *nested* nodes. That said, after everything is ready, the structure of document would look like:

```
<content id='content'></content>
content I am trying to access
```

not as you probably were expecting:

```
<!-- THAT IS NOT HOW IT’S COMPOSED -->
<content id='content'>content I am trying to access</content>
```

Fortunately, you are still having an access to `childNodes` within template context:

```
  Polymer({
      domReady: function() {
        var content = '';
        this.childNodes.array().forEach( function(el) {
          content += el.textContent; // do whatever you want here
        });
        console.log(content);
      }
  });

  //⇒ content I am trying to access
```

Hope it helps.